# Finding a specific word in a file and return a logical result

Tags: python

I'm a newbie in Python.  I'm trying to find a specific word from a file and retun the value success or fail.  This script works if the keyword is found but not when the keyword is not found.  Thank you for the help.

```
def check():
    datafile = open('data\CR_Daily201611070011.log')
    for line in datafile:
        if 'End of CR_Daily' in line:
            found = True
            break
    return found

found = check()
if found:
    print ("Success")
else:
    print ("Fail")
```

---

Here is the result if the keyword is not found:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "file_reader.py", line 26, in <module>
found = check()
File "file_reader.py", line 24, in check
return found
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'found' referenced before assignment"""
```

---

Comment: Have you read the error message? What is unclear about it? You need to set a value for `found` (for example `False`)

Comment: I read it but still not sure what to do.  It's working now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you never initialize `found`. In your function, your if statement never runs, which means that `found` is never created. This behavior can be demonstrated with a short example:

```
>>> if False:
        abc = True


>>> abc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    abc
NameError: name 'abc' is not defined
>>
```

This can be fixed by giving `found` a "default" value before using in your function:

```
def check():
    found = False
```

Comment: @Indomart Your welcome! But you should know, [that here at Stack Overflow up-votes are used to show thanks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment).

Answer (score 0):

Just specify `found` value at begining of your `check()`:

```
def check():
    found = False
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to assign a value to found. You can just return **True** if you found 'End of CR_Daily' and return **False** after the for. I rewrote your code like this:

```
def check():
    datafile = open('data\CR_Daily201611070011.log')
    for line in datafile:
        if 'End of CR_Daily' in line:
            return True
    return False

found = check()
if found:
    print ("Success")
else:
    print ("Fail")
```